# is it possible to use Dropzone.js without AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js, dropzone

Just a simple question. I am trying to integrate dropzone.js in my app. But I want to upload the files manually without using AJAX at all. is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: long answer yes, but why.... basically you bound to java-script (js) anyway so why no ajax, you would have to write js to do the work.... fake if it needs to...seems like your missing some key fundermentals. SO is not really about "is it possible q's" its more about this whative coded.. im trying to do y and having x problem. generally speaking i agree with Rory but that purely based on ......Why no AJAX, form submit and ajax... are both manual so i feel there is some home work you need do...